# Rest Assured: Verify xml value for of child tags

Tags: java, xml, rest, rest-assured

I am trying to compare element value `CUSTOMER` in below XML using Rest assured. I am not able to locate my tag where value `CUSTOMER` is present.

Once I am successful in comparing value I need to compare `INVOICE, ITEM, PRODUCT` and other details as well.

```
<resource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <CUSTOMERList xlink:href="http://thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/">CUSTOMER</CUSTOMERList>
    <INVOICEList xlink:href="http://thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/INVOICE/">INVOICE</INVOICEList>
    <ITEMList xlink:href="http://thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/ITEM/">**ITEM**</ITEMList>
    <PRODUCTList xlink:href="http://thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/PRODUCT/">PRODUCT</PRODUCTList>
</resource>
```

Below is my code java code:

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "http://thomas-bayer.com";
try {
    RestAssured.given().parameter("CUSTOMERList")
               .when().post("/sqlrest").then()
               .body("resource.CUSTOMERList", Matchers.equalTo("CUSTOMER"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Error generated after running code:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: XML path resource.CUSTOMERList doesn't match.
Expected: CUSTOMER
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `.text()` to retrieve the value of tag, as given below:

```
.body("resource.CUSTOMERList.text()",
    Matchers.equalTo("CUSTOMER"));
```